# Too many Outbound Connections

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, dotnet-httpclient

I have developed a mobile backend using .Net Core in which we are connecting to different third-party services to get user data and for this purpose, I have implemented Typed Client Approach for HTTP clients, below is an example of one of the Typed Client:

```
 public class NetworkClient : BaseClient
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private HttpClient _client;
    private ILogger _logger;
    public NetworkClient(HttpClient client,
                           AuthenticationHeader authHeader,
                           ILogger logger,
                           IConfiguration config) : base(client, authHeader, logger)
    {
        _config = config;
        _client = client;
        _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_config["V6BaseURL"]);
        _logger = logger;
        _authToken = authHeader.AuthHeader;
    }
}
```

And below is *BaseClient* code:

```
public class BaseClient
{
    private HttpClient _client;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public string _authToken { get; set; }
    private readonly string _correlationId;
    public BaseClient(HttpClient client,
                      AuthenticationHeader authHeader,
                      ILogger logger
                      )
    {
        _client = client;
        _client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        _logger = logger;
        _authToken = authHeader.AuthHeader;
        _correlationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
  


    #region Process Async

    public async Task<T> ProcessAsync<T>(HttpRequestMessage request, NamingStrategy namingStrategy)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_authToken))
        {
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _authToken);
        }

        HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
        try
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                _logger.Information(IntegrationLogger.GetLogMessage(_correlationId, HttpStatusCode.OK, GetType().Name,
                                                                    IntegrationLogger.GetActualAsyncMethodName(),
                                                                    $"Response Successfully Returned, ReqURI:{request.RequestUri}, StatusCode: {response.StatusCode}", null));

                var dezerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
                    {
                        NamingStrategy = namingStrategy
                    }
                };
                try
                {
                 
                    
                        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        T responseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString, dezerializerSettings);
                        return responseModel;
                    
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.Error(IntegrationLogger.GetLogMessage(_correlationId, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                                                        GetType().Name, IntegrationLogger.GetActualAsyncMethodName(),
                                                        ex.Message, null));
                    throw;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw await GetFailureResponseModel(response);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            response.Dispose();
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

But now the issue is that whenever we have high traffic spike, our backend performs too slow and I have found out that we are making too many TCP Connections and due to that we are also getting SNAT Port exhaustion issue. Check attached screenshots
[image]
[image]

Now, I really need to understand what can be the issue in our approach due to which my application is creating so many outbound connections and failing SNAT Ports as well.

The backend is deployed in Azure WebApp and it is using P3V3 tier Service plan.

Answer (score 0):

The [official docs about managing connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections?tabs=csharp) covers best practices which primarily are about reusing clients (and their internal client connection pools).

In your case, you could ensure the `NetworkClient` is instantiated as few times as possible or share `HttpClient` instaces within across instances. You can read more about recommended ways of using `HttpClient` objects in the [official .NET docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines).